# ggplot: percentage at top of bars but count on y-aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `geom_bar` in ggplot to make a chart that has counts on `y-aes` but on top of the bar the % of total group.
My data is `cp.dat2` and the column "orsok" has 9 factor variables.

i tried

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(cp.dat2, aes(x = as.factor(orsok))) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

And got this picture:
[image]

What I want is to get the counts on y-aes but keep the percentages at top of all the bars..

Also, can I change were the bars are? e.g put the bar with 9.16% at the front (where bar with 2,29% is).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the bars with `forcats::infreq()`. You can easily use counts for the y-position. This is done automatically for `geom_bar()`, whereas you have to access the computed statistics for the text with `after_stat()`. Note that `after_stat()` replaces the older `..stat..` notation and is more flexible.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

cp.dat2 <- data.frame(
  orsok = sample(41:51, 100, replace = TRUE)
)

ggplot(cp.dat2, aes(x = forcats::fct_infreq(factor(orsok)))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(
    stat = "count",
    aes(y = after_stat(count),
        label = after_stat(percent(count / sum(count)))),
    vjust = -0.25
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>